# How to make Google Maps V3 Directions Work with User Location Dectection - GeoCoder

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a conflict, between Directions & user GeoCode Detection.

If I do this:

```
var MapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

function initialize(lat,lng) {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
// var MapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
geocodeThis(MapCenter);
```

the directions work fine, but the GeoCoder doesn't get the user's location.

And if I do it like this:

```
// var MapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

function initialize(lat,lng) {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var MapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
geocodeThis(MapCenter);
```

the GeoCoder gets the user location, but when you click on the InfoWindow, and then in directions, the script doesn't do anything. Instead it should give you directions to that marker from your current (just GeoCoded) location.

Here is my [full code](http://pastebin.com/HxTCYJSU).

Comment: Don't put "not solved yet" into the title. As long as there is no accepted answer, we know it isn't solved.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: I rephrased the problem, @Lightness Races in Orbit

Comment: "the directions don't give directions" is not an improvement

Comment: I still haven't manange to solve this, any ideas ;o) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the variables with different names. They are both called "MapCenter", of course they conflict...

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Satoshi, they need to be the same name, since they are the center. I try to get the users' location, and then center the map based on that location. that works in the second example. But then when I open an InfoWindow, and then in "Directions", the directions don't work, which work in the first example. @satoshi